# access level on user and page wise

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

i have created a script for access level. where i give access on user basis for each page.

i have a table `pages` with links and page name and i have table `access` to store page ids with user id who has the access to which page

here is the structure of `pages`

```
`page_id  | code  | page  | href
 1        | ld    | New   | sl/lead.php
 2        | ld    | View  | sl/lead_view.php 
 3        | ld    | Edit  | sl/lead_edit.php
 4        | ld    | Delete| sl/lead_delete.php
 5        | cst   | New   | sl/customer.php`
```

`access` table

```
`aid | page_id | user_id
  1  | 1       | 1
  2  | 2       | 1
  3  | 3       | 1
  4  | 4       | 1
  5  | 5       | 1`
```

Giving access like this

```
<ul id="demo2" class="mnav">
    <li><a href="#">Sales</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Lead</a>
                <ul><table align="center" width="900px;">
                <?php $s1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE code='ld'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
                while($s2 = mysqli_fetch_array($s1)) { ?>
                <tr><td><li><?php echo $s2['page']; ?>  </td><td><input type="checkbox" name="sn[]" value="<?php echo $s2['page_id']; ?>" /> </li></td></tr>
                <?php } ?>
                </table>  
                </ul>
            </li>   

            <li><a href="#">Customer</a>
                <ul><table align="center" width="900px;">
                <?php $s1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE code='cst'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
                while($s2 = mysqli_fetch_array($s1)) { ?>
                <tr><td><li><?php echo $s2['page']; ?>  </td><td><input type="checkbox" name="sn[]" value="<?php echo $s2['page_id']; ?>" /> </li></td></tr>
                <?php } ?>
                </table>  
                </ul>
            </li>



</li>
</ul>
```

I am saving it like this

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $user = $_POST['user'];

    foreach($_POST['sn'] as $sn)
    {
     $sql = "insert into access (page_id, user_id, active) values (".$sn.", ".$user.", 1)";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($con));
    }
    }
```

User ID i am getting from a dropdown. Code works fine. But instead of `Delete` option i want to make it as `All`. When i check `All` checkbox, it should check all the value (New, View, Edit, Delete) from that code. I am not geting how to do it

Comment: You can use JAVASCRIPT or JQUERY framework

Comment: cant i do it in php ? as am naive in javascript

Comment: I think it is complicate to do that in PHP much better to use JAVASCRIPT or JQUERY framework for that

Comment: is there any examples for this?

Comment: If anything related to this is available in php or js please do let me know, as I have been trying to get it solved from couple of days.

Comment: Did your check all function already works?

Comment: Yes I did check

Comment: How you do that?

Comment: Sorry, I thought u were asking about the whole code, which works. But all check not working

Comment: You don't have any idea about javascript or jquery ajax?